# Every day specific new port blocked request spam at firewall log

Tags: security, port

At my server firewall log I found that there is majority of blocked request to one particular port which change every day aprox., lets say 4000 out of 5000 blocked requests per day, the remaining 1000 are regular port scans or viruses etc., but what about the 4000 ? It doesn't make any sense to me, what is most confusing (disturbing) that even from known trusted IP addresses. Today it is port 54905, yesterday 48251, day before 42775... Even though the IP addresses repeats there is at least several hundreds of them.

Is it global ? I mean do someone have same blocked request for these ports too ? Or someone know the origin of these requests ?

I know this question is kinda silly, but I wanna know what is going on. Here is the thing, my client IP is within list and I suspect that its virus running on his machine. I had to whitelist his IP otherwise fail2ban would ban his IP for port scanning, which is fine as long as he connect from home, but when he try to use the service while on mobile internet etc. he will get banned, which is why I'm asking this question, if I understood from where are these requests coming from I could make a rule to ignore these ports and not ban them, but when ports change every day and I don't know why, I just can't do that, only partial solution is to disable the port scan jail which is not what I wanna do.

Summary:
My problem is that clients gets banned while not on whitelist.
Current state is that they do get banned, just because of request to disallowed ports.
Desired state is to not have to whitelist their IP while port scan jail is still in action.

Comment: Honestly, it is impossible to understand what are you talking about. What is your problem, exactly, what is the current state of the system, and what is the desired state of the system you want to achieve?

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov edit, is it more clear now ?

Comment: Yes, that's better, but not clear. Do you have a server with fail2ban which bans your client for making wrong accesses to your server? If so, *why* they do port scans on your server at all? Do they have some malware, or do that intentionally? I think you're exploring the problem from the wrong side.

Comment: And, also, the most interesting is: why are you concerned with port scans at all? Well, they scan and scan, why do you care?

Comment: I would ask to scan for viruses and malware. This is very concerning. You might be able to block the request which are concering by using traffic dumping using whireshark.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov Yea, I have server with fail2ban which bans my clients for wrong access to my server. Why they do port scans to my server ? That's the thing, I don't know, but they are 100% legit, which means it isn't intentional at all. Its not even regular port scan just one particular port every day. Could be malware or some weird feature of system/apps I'm unaware of, could be bug in ufw, routing tables or some wrong configuration somewhere, there is a lot of possibilities.

Comment: Analyze the traffic with whireshark and see what it's doing. Port scans are happing all the time from china or russia. You could either block them or ignore them

Comment: `iptables -A port-scan -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,ACK,FIN,RST RST -m limit --limit 1/s -j RETURN



iptables -A port-scan -j DROP``

Answer (score 0):

```
iptables -A port-scan -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,ACK,FIN,RST RST -m limit --limit 1/s -j RETURN



iptables -A port-scan -j DROP
```

a rule to block furtive port scanning. A furtive port scan is a scan that detects closed ports to deduce open ports